# C++ random number generator hung up

Tags: c++

Whenever I attempt to run my code, the program gets "hung up" and will not print out the value of r2eff. I am not sure why it will not. Any help would be appreciated. A sample value for r2effTemp would be 10 and stddev would be about .05 (5%).

```
unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
std::mt19937 generator(seed);
normal_distribution<double> rand(r2effTemp, (r2effTemp*stddev));   
r2effTemp = rand(generator);
cout<<r2effTemp<<endl;
```

Thank you!

Comment: It is hard to tell what is wrong, the code sample is not enough, but this [example does work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944111/creating-a-gaussian-random-generator-with-a-mean-and-standard-deviation/19944164#19944164), it may help.

Comment: A more appropriate seed might be `std::random_device{}()`, assuming an implementation that uses it effectively.

Comment: ill check it out. It has stumped me too.

Comment: I do not have this issue in vs2013...It works just fine from what I can test with what you have given(using your example values).

Comment: the code works http://ideone.com/qQkjCy (but `r2effTemp*stddev` is strange for Standard deviation)

Comment: I know it is strange but I want it to vary 5% from r2eff so that was the solution my head came up with

Comment: That is strange that it works for you? Every time I attempt to run it on my computer using the example values I get hung up at the r2effTemp =  rand(generator) line

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the following line that is causing this "infinite loop" : r2effTemp = rand(generator); and yes, it is working in an online compiler but not my computer