# test1.cpp:9:77: error: no match for call to ‘(const std::normal_distribution<double>) (std::mt19937&)’

Tags: c++

I have this code :

```
class Y {
    private:
        std::normal_distribution<double> N;
    public:
        Y() : N(0,1) {}
        double operator()(const double & x, std::mt19937 G) const { return x + N(G); }
};
```

And I have this error :

> error: no match for call to ‘(const std::normal_distribution)
>   (std::mt19937&)’

for the line :

```
    double operator()(const double & x, std::mt19937 G) const { return x + N(G); }
```

Answer (score 3):

Operator `std::normal_distribution<T>::operator()(Generator& g)` is a non-const member function and thus cannot be called for a constant object. Just remove `const` from your function definition:

```
double operator()(const double & x, std::mt19937 &G) { return x + N(G); }
```

Also note that you most likely want to pass generator argument by reference

Comment: Or make the normal dist mutable? It may be preferable in this case

Comment: @innisfree Distribution itself could use `mutable` internally, but since it doesn't, I think it is better to avoid using it. It might confuse people into thinking the function doesn't modify any state, but doesn in at least [some implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25684539/1143634).